# JW-Player - How to unload?

Tags: jquery, jwplayer

My JS Code:

```
$('body').append('<div id="mediaplayer"></div>');

$.getScript('js/mplayer/jwplayer.js', function ()
{
jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
flashplayer: "js/mplayer/player.swf",
file: ''+v_url+'',
autostart: "true"
}); 

  $('#mediaplayer_wrapper').css('z-index','107').css('width','853px').css('height','505px').css('padding','10px').addClass('bg_one').center();
    });
```

I close the player with:

```
$('#mediaplayer, #mediaplayer_wrapper').remove();
```

but when i load the player again (with an other url) ... the player did not start. If there maybe an unload function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got it

```
jwplayer('mediaplayer').remove();
```

Comment: +1 Because this worked for me and other solution(s) didn't. Thanks

Comment: http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/javascript-interaction/14965/player-removal-using-remove/

Answer (score 3):

The jwplayer(...).remove() is a function from the jwplayer api - this is not jquery.

> remove() - Being the reverse of the setup() call, this call will remove a JW Player from the page. It ensures the player stops playback, the DOM is re-set to its original state and all event listeners and timers are cleaned up.

So you have to call your jwplayer(...).setup(...) again after removing it.
This remove() has nothing to do with a jquery-remove. detach is not a jwplayer function.

Answer (score 2):

try with **[jQuery.detach](http://api.jquery.com/detach/)** instead of `remove`, it is cleary written on document

> The .detach() method is the same as
>   .remove(), except that .detach() keeps
>   all jQuery data associated with the
>   removed elements. This method is
>   useful when removed elements are to be
>   reinserted into the DOM at a later
>   time.

```
$('#mediaplayer, #mediaplayer_wrapper').detach();
```

Hopefully it works :)

Comment: Hi diEcho! Same problem. The Player did not start, no error message.